# Symlink directory into an existing directory (merging files)

Tags: bash, symbolic-link

I have a `ghc` directory containing `ghci.conf`:

```
$ tree ghc                                                                                                 
ghc
└── ghci.conf

0 directories, 1 file
```

And I want to create symbolic link at `$HOME/.ghc`, but the latter directory contains other files and directories.

When doing:

```
$ ln -s -f ghc ~/.ghc
```

I get a symbolic link to my `ghc` under `$HOME/.ghc`, which is not what I intended:

```
$ ls -l ~/.ghc                                                                                                                
total 16
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jviotti  staff    41 Nov 30 20:40 ghc -> /Users/jviotti/dotfiles/link/ghc
-rw-r--r--  1 jviotti  staff  1883 Nov 30 20:34 ghci_history
drwxr-xr-x  3 jviotti  staff   102 Jul  9 13:35 x86_64-darwin-7.6.3
drwxr-xr-x  3 jviotti  staff   102 Nov 11 13:51 x86_64-darwin-7.8.3
```

A quick solution do accomplish this would be to iterate trough the contents of `ghc` and execute `ln -s` on each file, however I was wondering if there is an easier way to instruct `ls` to merge the files automatically of trying to create a symbolic link to a directory from an existing directory.

Does such option exist?

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if a misunderstand the question, but is 'rsync' an option to get the directories in sync and THEN recreating the symlink you want?